# Como saber qual é a página respondendo ao request JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Tenho várias páginas `JSP` , e trato todas elas no meu `servlet` Controle.
Gostaria de saber se tem como identificar qual a página que esta sendo exibida para que eu possa fazer todos os tratamentos , `requests` e `responses`, específicos desta pagina .
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode no JSP retornar uma variável com o nome dele próprio. Vc ta usando algum framework? Spring talvez? A propósito, existe alguma implicação que te impede de ter vários servlets? Na vdd me parece a solução mais apropriada, não?

Comment: Nao tenho nenhum problema em ter varios servlets. Gostaria de fazer tudo em um servlet so, mas nao vejo problema.

Comment: Poderia especificar que tipo de tratamento exatamente você deseja fazer? Seria verificar a URL acessada? Se for isso, aconselho fortemente a não reinventar a roda e usar um framework como Spring MVC. Você pode mapear uma URL para um método simplesmente com uma anotação. Tenho um projeto completo de exemplo, [veja aqui](https://github.com/utluiz/spring-examples/blob/master/agenda-web-completa/src/main/java/br/com/starcode/agenda/controller/EntradaController.java).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar usar o retorno do método `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()`.